# Cannot trim videos in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I am using Laravel-ffmpeg and I try to clip video. Here's my code:

```
public function clip($id)
    {
        $video = Video::where('id', $id)->first();

        $vid = asset('storage/app/public/uploads/videos/');

        $ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();

        $media = \FFMpeg::fromFilesystem($vid)->open($video->file_name);

        dd($media);

        $video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(30), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(15));

    }
```

The problem:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpeg::fromFilesystem() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem, string given
```

I try to implement that script but it doesn't work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You're giving a string instead of passing the actual video. It needs to implement the `Filesystem` interface from laravel. `asset()` returns a string, I think what you're looking for is the `Storage` class within laravel.

Comment: @Classified so what should i use here?

Comment: The function `Storage::get(FILE_PATH_HERE)` gets the contents of a file. Which in this case would be your video. I don't really know what FFMpeg needs as an input, but try it and tell me if it worked.